# Can't display Ajax value

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem with my ajax, it can't display data from database.

**Controller**

```
public function rating() {
 $rating = $this->db->select_avg('hasil_rating')
                    ->get('tb_rating')->row_array();
 echo json_encode($rating);
}
```

**Ajax**

```
function rate() {
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '<?php echo base_url()."rate/rating"?>',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    $('#aaaa').val(data);
  }
});
```

**input**

```
<input id="aaaa" type="text" value="">
```

when I used `val()` the result is **[object Object]** and when I used `html()` the result is **empty**. But when I use `console.log(data)` it works.

Comment: it means that `data` is an object, try to get meaningful information by traversing `data` most likely the value you want is inside one of the properties, `console.log(data)` to find out

Comment: 'console.log(data)' is works, but I want make the output to the id="aaaa"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert json object to string and it will work.

```
$('#aaaa').val(data.someVar);
```

For example,

```
var jsonVal = {val1:'one',val2:'two'};
alert(jsonVal); // it will print [object][object]
alert(jsonVal.val1); // one
alert(jsonVal.val2); // two
alert(JSON.stringify(jsonVal)) // it will print {val1:'one',val2:'two'}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: how to display just the `one`?

Comment: you mean, you want to set like `'one'` as the value of `#aaaa` ?

Comment: what if `'one'` is from database?

Comment: what are you getting when you try this ? `console.log(data)`

Comment: I get value from **jsonVal.val1** which mean is `one`

Comment: what are you having for this -> `console.log(data.hasil_rating);` ?

Comment: nice to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first decode the json in your ajax success.

Use this.

```
function rate() {
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '<?php echo base_url()."rate/rating"?>',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    var d = $.parseJSON(data);
    $('#aaaa').val(d.value);
  }
});
```

Using this you can access different values from data and set the value in your html.

### Update

In your controller you can return the value using json_encode like

```
echo json_encode(array("success"=>true,"msg1"=>"test ajax","msg2"=>"test ajax 2"));
```

In your ajax success function to get the value of msg1 you can use

```
var d = $.parseJSON(data);
alert(d.msg1); //will return "test ajax"
alert(d.msg2); //will return "test ajax 2"
```

By this way you can access each and every value from your json object.

Comment: d.value is just an example you need to change 'value' with the key in your json object. Show me the response you are getting in data and I will guide you.

Comment: I really confused, it's my first time using ajax. can you give me some example?

Comment: I have updated my answer, hope this is clear to you now? Let me know if you need any other help. @ImamNur

Answer (score 0):

You have to require **$.pasrseJSON** before use the data

```
function rate() {
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '<?php echo base_url()."rate/rating"?>',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    data=$.parseJSON(data);
    $('#aaaa').val(data.var_name);
  }
});
```